# 400 Error when trying to authenticate against MS Graph with OnBehalfOf Flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, postman, office-js, office-addins

I'm currently developing a TypeScript add-in for Outlook that uses the Microsoft Graph API and am using the on-behalf-of authentication flow.

Following the Microsoft docs and their code samples resulted into this code:

```
let userTokenEncoded = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({
   forMSGraphAccess: true,
   allowSignInPrompt: true,
   allowConsentPrompt: true
});

const form = new FormData();
form.set("grant_type","urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
form.set("client_id","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
form.set("client_secret", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
form.set("assertion", userTokenEncoded);
form.set("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
form.set("requested_token_use", "on_behalf_of");

const accessToken = await fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token", {
   method: "POST",
   body: form
});

// MS Graph Endpoint Access Here
```

which gives me a 400 Bad Request error.

---

Doing the same thing in Postman however works without any problems. I can use the access token with the MS Graph API flawlessly.

Comment: Have you gone through the doc -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Javascript#on-behalf-of-provider?

Comment: Yes, and it also returns a 400 error AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type. Request origin: 'https://localhost:3000'.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases for token redemption (using authorization_code mode): from Web Application and from Single-Page Application (PKCE).

When using a SPA, Azure Identity requires that the token redemption comes from a browser (not a web server). The request for the code exchange must contain the 'Origin' header. If not, you get the error: "Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests"

[image]

You can refer Microsoft official doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app,this should help to solve the issue.

Code samples - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples